# Entity Data Model and Encrypted Columns in DB

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

We have couple of tables on SQl Server DB for which we want to encrypt some columns that have sensitive customer data. We are using EDM for accessing,updating, inserting.. database data. We will encrypt some already existing columns for few tables using a symmetric key on database. What updates do i need to make in ED to accommodate the encrypted columns?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will be of some help for others...we eventually didn't use the symmetric encryption on DB level, we encrypted the columns in the application and saved the encrypted data as string and decrypted the col's on retrieving the data. It is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case you should always encrypt data before putting it into the database and decrypt when pulling . EF has nothing builtin to support you with any kind of encryption/decryption builtin.

Thats how you should do it. 
I hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

It does work apart from your search queries and order by's are completely shot and the main reason why I'm umming and arring about encrypting at all.